# Is it possible to do development of Dapr based applications without using Docker Desktop?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-desktop, dapr

Based on the documentation for Dapr mentioned at :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/dapr-for-net-developers/getting-started . It looks like Docker Desktop is mandatory perquisite as part of Dapr setup in local environment.

The Docker company recently announced that it would be making changes in its Docker Desktop subscription terms. With this update it is not possible to install Docker Desktop in the local development environment. Can anyone help me to know how to continue Dapr based application development without Docker Desktop in this case.

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance?